# connect to socks5 proxy with IKEv2 certificate using golang 1.10.2

Tags: go, proxy, socks

I use Go 1.10.2 for my client application.

I'm trying to connect to a socks5 proxy that requires username, password and IKEv2 certificate file.

this is what I've got so far:

```
 func socks5(proxyAdress string, url string, user string, password string) {
        auth := proxy.Auth{User: user, Password: password}
        if proxy, err := proxy.SOCKS5("tcp", proxyAdress, &auth, proxy.Direct);  err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("error: %v", proxy)
        } else {
            tr := &http.Transport{Dial: proxy.Dial}

            // Create client
            myClient := &http.Client{
                Transport: tr,
            }

            if resp, err2 := myClient.Get(url); err2 != nil {
                log.Fatalf("error: %v", err2)
            } else {
                if bodyBytes, err3 := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body); err3 != nil {
                    log.Fatalf("error: %v", err3)
                } else {
                    str := string(bodyBytes)
                    log.Printf(str)
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

when I execute this function with the proper parameters

I get an error from the server that I don't have permissions to access the web page I requested. that's because I didn't specify the IKEv2 key file.

so.. first.. how do I do that ?

and 2nd... `Dial` is deprecated.. I'm supposed to use `DialContext` but has no idea how

thanks ! :)

## update

the OS that I use is MacOS High Sierra 10.13.4

the problem is that for example when I execute

```
socks5("il7.nordvpn.com:1080", "http://ifconfig.me/ip","MY_USER","MY_PASS")
```

the error that I get is

```
2018/05/15 23:34:49 error: Get http://ifconfig.me/ip: socks connect tcp ifconfig.me:80->ifconfig.me:80: EOF
```

I don't know where to provide the IKEv2 certificate

Comment: a cool guy on #go-nuts in freenode showed me a solution to the deprecated Dial. still doesn't resolve the IKEv2 issue. https://play.golang.org/p/NfXO9STkFin

Comment: Are you absolutely 100% sure that you have an "IKEv2" certificate? You need to go triple check this. IKEv2 certificates are used to set up IPSec, which is something the OS does, in conjunction with an IPSec daemon such as strongswan. In no case would you put an IKEv2 certificate into your own application.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - i'm trying to connect to a paid ipsec vpn called nordvpn that uses IKEv2 certificate.

Comment: OK, then you need to set up IPSec on your computer first.

Comment: @ufk what operating system are you on? Also can you post the actual error you get?

Comment: @voutasaurus - updated main post

Comment: On the context subquestion, the field Dial on http.Transport is deprecated in favor of DialContext but DialContext is not supported by golang.org/x/net/proxy. This seems like a problem that would be best addressed by the maintainers of golang.org/x/net/proxy by filing a bug report here: https://github.com/golang/go/issues

Comment: This isn't an answer but you might want to use the Proxy field on https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Transport instead of the golang.org/x/net/proxy package. Here's an example: https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/golang/go@23b687eccbcc68f44acf34fd5971f0f5c04d90de/-/blob/src/net/http/transport_test.go#L962:1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to set up IPSec on your computer first.

**The steps to setup IPSec**

1. Initial configurations (only once at the first time)
2. Start a VPN connection

Follow [here](https://www.softether.org/4-docs/2-howto/9.L2TPIPsec_Setup_Guide_for_SoftEther_VPN_Server/5.Mac_OS_X_L2TP_Client_Setup)

Comment: thank you for your answer. so even if I set the initial configuration there is no way to start and stop it programatically and to also decide which requests will go though the vpn and which won''t ?